# How to disable the "Get Started" tab in Theia before the first execution?

Tags: visual-studio-code, theia

I have a Theia IDE built in a docker.

Every time I launch a new docker and open a python file for the first time, I got some annoying pop-up:

- A new tab: `Python - Get Started`
- A pop up: `Linter pylint not installed`

Both have a `Do not show again` option. However, it does not work in my use case because every time a user connects, he will get a new Docker.

I tried to look in the settings and preferences but could not find where to disable these pop-ups.

I also tried to look at the settings files (launch.json for example) after having clicked the `Do not show again button` but nothing change.

The perfect solution for me would be to add a line in the launch.json file to tell Theia to never display those pop-up in the first place but I am not sure it is possible.

If you know a way to do it (in the launch.json or another way) I would be pleased to hear it!

If you know how to do it in VS code I would also be pleased to hear about it as Theia took a lot from VS code

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by observing which files were changed last on the docker.

I found out that you have to write `"python.showStartPage": false` in `/home/theia/.theia/settings.json`

However, it was not enough, I also had to add some lines in `/home/theia/.theia/plugin-storage/global-state.json`.
I don't know which lines exactly as I just copied-pasted the full file from a previous execution. But I would guess that it is one of the lines beginning with `gettingStarted.overrideCategory`